# 'list' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, web, flask

i get 'list' object has no attribute 'id' error. I dont know why.

```
@posts.route("/post/<int:post_id>", methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required 
def course_post(post_id):
    post=Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    chapters=Chapter.query.filter_by(post_id=post_id).all()
    chapter_id = chapters.id
    videos=Videos.query.filter_by(chapter_id=chapter_id).all()
    return render_template('course.html', title=post.course_name, post=post, chapters = chapters)
```

```
class Chapter(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key= True)
    chapter_no = db.Column(db.Integer)
    chapter_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    chapter_desc = db.Column(db.String(50))
    chapter_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    vi = db.relationship('Videos', backref='topic', lazy=True)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Chapter('{self.chapter_no}', '{self.chapter_name}', '{self.chapter_desc}', '{self.chapter_date}', '{self.post_id}'"





class Videos(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key= True)
    video_no = db.Column(db.Integer)
    video_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, index=True)
    video_file = db.Column(db.String(200))
    yout_code = db.Column(db.String(200))
    video_description = db.Column(db.Text(100))
    uploaded_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    rating = db.Column(db.Integer())
    chapter_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('chapter.id'), nullable=False)
    c_v = db.relationship("Chapter", foreign_keys=chapter_id)  #


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Videos('{self.video_no}','{self.video_name}', '{self.video_file}', '{self.yout_code}', '{self.video_description}', '{self.uploaded_date}', '{self.rating}', '{self.chapter_id}'"
```

i am trying to get all the videos for each chapter in the Videos table using chapters.id as foreign key
Please what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You Chapter CLass will return a list of records....you have to loop through it to do what you expect to do

Comment: I know but I am still getting an error

Comment: Can you post an edit of your code after changes ?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your function like this

```
@posts.route("/post/<int:post_id>", methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required 
def course_post(post_id):
    post=Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    chapters=Chapter.query.filter_by(post_id=post_id).all()
    chapter_id = chapters and chapters[0].id
    videos=Videos.query.filter_by(chapter_id=chapter_id).all()
    return render_template('course.html', title=post.course_name, post=post, chapters = chapters)
```

Now it uses first chapter ID it founds. I don't know if this is something you want though.

If you want to get list of chapter ids you can do it like this

```
chapter_id = [c.id for c in chapters]
```

But I don't know how ORM library you are using handles filtering by lists.

Comment: Thanks alot. It almost worked. just that when i tried to loop the video in template, it doesn't loop correctly. This is the code for the loop:                                                                             
     ` {% for chapter in chapters %}

            {% for video in videos %}
            {% endfor %}
               

     {% endfor %} `   .

Comment: my purpose is to display all chapters and its videos for each chapter using loop.

Comment: the loop does not give error. The loop for the chapters is ok. the major problem i am having is looping the video correctly.  What it does is repeating the videos of the first chapter accross the others instead of looping the correct videos.

Comment: Yes, because you are searching your videos based only one chapters ID, as I said in my answer. Try that `chapter_id = [c.id for c in chapters]` when defining chapter_id variable. You may need to modify how you search videos, depending on your ORM library.

Comment: you mean like this: `@posts.route("/post/<int:post_id>", methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required 
def course_post(post_id):
    post=Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    chapters=Chapter.query.filter_by(post_id=post_id).all()
    chapter_id = [c.id for c in chapters]
    videos=Videos.query.filter_by(chapter_id=chapter_id).all()
    return render_template('course.html', title=post.course_name, post=post, chapters = chapters, videos = videos)`

Comment: where should i use `chapter_id = [c.id for c in chapters]` ? because I get Error binding parameter.

Comment: Yes, in case it works. It may fail on the line you define `videos` variable, but in that case you have to read your database library API and see how to search based on list instead of string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212537/discussion-between-ex4-and-ozaveshe-balogun).

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the parent class (Chapter) of the model.py

`medias = db.relationship('Videos', backref='Chapter',  lazy='subquery')`

The code below pulls the query and sub query of parent and child. This code does that: 
chapters = db.session.query(Chapter).filter_by(post_id=post_id).all() 
i.e:

```
@posts.route("/post/<int:post_id>", methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required 
def course_post(post_id):
    post=Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    #chapters=Chapter.query.filter_by(post_id=post_id).all()
    chapters = db.session.query(Chapter).filter_by(post_id=post_id).all()    
    return render_template('course.html', title=post.course_name, post=post, chapters = chapters)
```

Then in my template, to loop the chapters and videos for each chapter in the template:

```
 {% for v in chapters %}
            <h7><a href=""><span class="plus">+</span>{{ v.chapter_name }}</a></h7> <br><br>
              <div class="descDiv">
                 {% for media in v.medias %}
                 <p class="desc">{{  media.video_name }}</p>
                 {% endfor %}

              </div>
        {% endfor %}
```